# import google-play-service: Resource '/HomeActivity' already exists

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok... this is my problem. When I try to import google-play-service, Eclipse show me this error:

**Resource '/HomeActivity' already exists.**

**Reason:**

**Resource '/HomeActivity' already exists.**

Then, all the projects that are imported, have red globes with X (some error). And the library is not usefull.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused because Eclipse tries to import samples of Google Play Services that have the same Activities/Project names.

To avoid these errors, just import the google-play-services_lib instead of the google_play_services folder.

Example:
adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

Package_A= "Is Library" is checked.

Package_B= "Is Library" is checked. References Package_A.

Package_C= "Is Library" is checked. References Package_B.

Package_D= "Is Library" is NOT checked. References Package_C.

If you have HomeActivity inside both Package_B and Package_C = ERROR

If the way you reference the package is not what I described above= ERROR

Answer (score -1):

The reason why this is happening is because HomeActivity is present both in your project as well as in Google Play library. 
Rename your HomeActivity to another name which is not the in play library project